# How to load data into java program without bloating main method

Tags: java, oop, initialization

I'm looking for some object oriented design help basically.

At the start of my program I need to load a whole bunch of data into the program(not from a database or anywhere; in this case I'm just loading it into the program) by building objects and assigning variables. However this takes up a lot of room and I feel like I'm just clogging up the main method and making it unreadable.

I'm wondering what's the right way to approach this is, as far as OOP goes.

I tried to make a class `SubjectBuilder`, and create everything in the constructor or variable space, and then create a new object in the main method. But it seems that alldata is out of the scope of the main method so when I need to manipulate it later I can't.

```
Student jack = new Student("Jack Smith");   // Creating all the Student objects
Student jim = new Student("Jim Lucas");
Student beck = new Student("Beck Barber");
Student ann = new Student("Ann Walker");
Student lucy = new Student("Lucy Boxer");

Subject maths = new Subject("Maths");       //  Creating all the Subject objects 
Subject business = new Subject("Business");
Subject java = new Subject("Java");
Subject design = new Subject("Design");
Subject project = new Subject("Project");

business.addStudent(jack, 70);
business.addStudent(jim, 65);
business.addStudent(beck, 70);
business.addStudent(ann, 83);
business.addStudent(lucy, 78);
```

^^ That's a snippet data I need to load. I have a bunch of marks for each subject.
At this stage I only have the `Application` class, `Subject` class ([HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) of student and Integer mark), and `Student`.

All I need to do is create this program that displays individual data for students or subjects and allows changes to particular marks etc. I'm confident I could complete the whole project in the main method but I feel like that's not very object oriented. I just don't know how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Can't you pass `business` from `main` to something other than `main` (an other class constructor, a function, whatever...)  which will create all the subjects and add them to `business`? I'm not sure I get your problem very well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, how about creating a method to do this so it is not in your main

e.g.

```
Class MyClass {

public void main (String args[]) {

       myClass mc = new MyClass();
       mc.loaddata ();
}

private void loadData () {
}
```

Now in your loadData method you could load this data from a CSV file maybe?  See http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense to me and I had considered something like it. However, once I load the files, I'm actually unable to manipulate the objects in the main method, or any method at all, for that matter?

Comment: Sorry, I am not catching what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

A simple suggestion for: create a StudentFactory to encapsulate students instantiation, the facory method might looks like: public List createAllStudents();

And the same to Subject class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to access the students from the business class you could do the following

```
business.addStudent(new Student("Jack Smith"), 70);
business.addStudent(new Student("Jim Lucas"), 65);
business.addStudent(new Student("Beck Barber"), 70);
business.addStudent(new Student("Ann Walker"), 83);
business.addStudent(new Student("Lucy Boxer"), 78);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your data in arrays or some other data structure like

```
String names = {"Jack Smith","John","Asley"};
int grades = {70,65,85}; //you can generate local or global array , its up to you 

int main()
{
     for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
         business.load(names[i],grades[i]);
}
```

//Do your work in load method

Answer (score 0):

You should use a map to hold your students, and use `Long` or `String` or any other immutable class as your key. I recommend using a `Map` because it's `O(1)` to access data from this kind of collection, against `O(n)` if you use, for instance, an `ArrayList<Students>`.

```
private Map<Long, Student> students = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you should move your loading data to a method such as:

```
private void loadStudents(){
    student.put(1L , new Student("Jack Smith"));
    student.put(2L , new Student("Joe Doe"));
    student.put(3L , new Student("Jane Doe"));
}
```

For your `Subject` you could use again some map:

```
private void loadSubjects(){
    subjects.put("MATH" , new Subject("Mathematics"));
    subjects.put("JAVA" , new Subject("Java"));
    subjects.put("DESING_PATTERNS" , new Subject("DesingPatterns"));
    //for instance you could have more advanced subjects such as:
    subjects.put("C++" , new Subject("C++" , "lecture" , "class 101" , "prof. T. Richards")); 
}
```

Since by calling an object's constructor means that that object is ready for use, you should call your `loadStudent()` (and possibly `loadSubjects()` method, or any methods you use to load your data into the application) into this constructor.

```
public BusinessLogic(){
    loadStudents();
    loadSubjects();
    //and so on
}
```

This is the prefered way against having to call load data methods on your newly created object, and always remembering you have to call these methods before using your object:

```
BusinessLogic business = new BusinessLogic();
business.calculateFinalGrades(); // NOT GOOD BECAUSE YOU HAVE FORGOTTEN TO CALL loadStudents();
```

So, you'll end up having something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    buildUI();//build your command line interface / graphical user interface
    BusinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();//you can probably now make this object a Singleton in order to prevent having multiple instances
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, building the whole application in the main is not the way to do it. In my opinion you should build a class that provides data let's say `DataProvider` that has methods for providing given data. As there are multiple ways of storing data, you can make this an interface/ abstract class depending on the common code. As your project can evolve and later maybe you want to extract data from DB or XML or something else. Like this it will be loose coupled and easy to replace. It might look like this:

```
 interface DataProvider<T> {
      Collection<T> loadData();
      //...other useful methods
 }

 class DummyStudentDataProvider implements DataProvide<Student> {
      Collection<Student> loadData() {
           ///...your logic
      }     
 }
```

I used generics as the same logic could be used for different classes that you might need. Hope this helps you.